# How to handle hasRole() response

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have the following hasRole() protection on antMatchers:

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/posts/myPosts").hasRole("USER")
```

How to handle response if user doesn't have role USER? When I do GET on `/api/posts/myPosts` with user without USER role I get response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-04-14T12:43:31.233+0000",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "path": "/api/posts/myPosts"
}
```

Is it possible to throw own exception and handle it later in class annotated `@RestControllerAdvice`?

I tried other way to achieve that by adding `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")` on the method level, then Spring throws `AccessDeniedException` and it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Filters happens before controllers are even resolved so exceptions thrown from filters can't be caught by a Controller Advice. Instead, Create an Authentication Entry Point like

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException ae) throws IOException, ServletException {
       //Here do whatever you want to do with the exception: ae
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Access Denied");
    }
}
```

Register this CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint within WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter like

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        ...
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/posts/myPosts").hasRole("USER")
        ...
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint)
        ...
}
```